# rxjs take operator - to limit results with async pipe

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-httpclient, rxjs6, angular-observable

i can't limit the showed result in the template using the rxjs take() operator, the template shows me always all records.

The api http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users returns 10 elements, i'd like to take only four of them.

```
[service]
public getData(): Observable<User[]> {
    return this.http.get<User[]>(`http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`).pipe(
       take(4)
      );
  }

[component]
export class GridComponent implements OnInit {

  _data : Observable<User[]>;

  constructor(public _ds : DataService) {  
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._data = this._ds.getData();
  }
}

[template]
<tr *ngFor="let d of _data | async">
        <td>{{d.id}}</td>
        <td>{{d.name}}</td>
        <td>{{d.email}}</td>
        <td>{{d.phone}}</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```js
    return this.http.get<[any]>(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`).pipe(
      map(x => x.slice(0, 4)))
```

This is the way that your service should look like.

You are using the rxjs `take` operator, that will take the first **4 responses** of a stream. So in your case it will return the first four responses from the server (that includes the first response of the server, that contains an array of 10 elements).

To achieve the desired result (take the first four elements of the incoming array) you must use rxjs `map` operator in order to **modify the incoming** http result, like shown.

In other words `take` **counts the emitted responses** from a stream and **dosen't modify the stream data** itself.